# WinError 10038 an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: windows, sockets, python-3.x

Im making an conection system for my domotica system but I get an error which I can't solve.
This is my script:

```
import insteon
import time

insteon.connect('10.20.0.195', 9761)
while 1:
    insteon.send('x10', 'N', '10', 'on')
    time.sleep(5)
    insteon.send('x10', 'N', '10', 'off')
```

the module insteon:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
            import socket
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            def connect(ip, port):
                import socket
                s.connect((ip, port))
            def close():
                import socket
                s.close()
            def send(prot, house, unit, action):
                import socket
                import binascii
                import time
                import sys
                if prot == 'x10':
                    units = {'1': '6', '2': 'E', '3': '2', '4': 'A', '5': '1', '6': '9', '7': '5', '8': 'D', '9': '7', '10': 'F', '11': '3', '12': 'B', '13': '0', '14': '8', '15': '4', '16': 'C'}
                    houses = {'A': '6', 'B': 'E', 'C': '2', 'D': 'A', 'E': '1', 'F': '9', 'G': '5', 'H': 'D', 'I': '7', 'J': 'F', 'K': '3', 'L': 'B', 'M': '0', 'N': '8', 'O': '4', 'P': 'C'}
                    unitcode = units[unit]
                    housecode = houses[house]
                    smessage1 = str('0263') + str(housecode) + str(unitcode) + str('00')
                    if action == 'on':
                        smessage2 = str('0263') + str(housecode) + str('280')
                    elif action == 'off':
                        smessage2 = str('0263') + str(housecode) + str('380')   
                    else:
                        sys.exit("Wrong action")
                elif prot == 'insteon':
                    if action == 'on':
                        SMESSAGE1 = str('0262') + str(id) + str('0011ff')
                    elif action == 'off':
                        SMESSAGE1 = str('0262') + str(id) + str('001300')
                    else:
                        sys.exit("Wrong choice")
                message1 = binascii.unhexlify(smessage1)
                if prot == 'x10':
                    message2 = binascii.unhexlify(smessage2)
                s.send(message1)
                time.sleep(1)
                if prot == 'x10':
                    s.send(message2)
                time.sleep(2)
                s.close() # You can't use the socket after this

            def receive():
                import socket
                import binascii
                import time
                import sys

                BUFFER_SIZE = 2048

                data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                data2 = binascii.b2a_hex(data).decode('ascii')
                return (data2)
```

But if i run the script I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Z:\programeren\repository's\red-cloud2\python backend\x10_server.py", line 8, in <module>
insteon.send('x10', 'N', '10', 'off')
File "Z:\programeren\repository's\red-cloud2\python backend\insteon.py", line 37, in send
s.send(message1)
OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

I use python 3 for the scripts and I'm running this from a windows  7 pc.

Comment: i got this error when running flask from cmd within PyCharm. Switched to Windows CMD Window and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your send function includes a call to `socket.close`. This will cause any subsequent operations on the socket to fail.